# How i can deploy my j2ee application in cloud servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, cloud, java-war

I am new to j2ee and java web apps development. I have an query about how to deploy the build WAR file into cloud.

i.e, Weather Cloud systems provide j2ee servers for running our java based web apps or not.

If so, please provide me the links of cloud j2ee servers.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to deploy a .war file and not taking care of any config process, you should then look for a Java PaaS.

The way will depend on the PaaS you choose. [This](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html) is a specific way for a PaaS, but a similar process could be follow for another PaaS. You usually have a GUI interface, which could help you to deploy in several Java stacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install your application and don't want to spend a lot of time configuring your environment, you might want to try using Tin. This is a one-click automatic generation of development environment software. I use it a lot. It might help you, too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).